# AngularJS calling function in parent window from child

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to have a multi page/window application where a dashboard page controls a list of children (windows). the dashboard should be able to call functions in the children and vice versa. In this context, i have a parent and a child html where the child fails to invoke a function in the parent page. Can someone pls tell me what i am missing?

Parent.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Parent</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="submitExample">
  <script>
  console.log(window);
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window',  function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.text = 'hello';
      $window.CallParent = function() {
            $scope.list = ['parent call']
     console.log("parent function called");
     $scope.apply();
        }
      $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.text) {
          $scope.list.push(this.text);
          $scope.text = '';
        }
      };
    }]);
</script>

<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="child" title=" child " onClick=window.open("child.html");>Click here to open the child window</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

child.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>child</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="submitExample">
  <script>
  console.log(window);
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window',  function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.text = 'hello';
      $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.text) {
          $scope.list.push(this.text);
          $scope.text = '';
   $window.opener.CallParent();
        }
      };
    }]);
</script>

<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The error seen is 
    **DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at b.$scope.submit (file:///C:/temp/html/child.html:24:18)**

Comment: The angular controller is just same class, not same instance, so you'll have to pass anything by using param `$window.opener.CallParent(this.text);`

Comment: Scripts trying to access a [frame's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) content are subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), and cannot access most of the properties in the other window object if it was loaded from a different domain. This also applies to a script inside a frame trying to access its parent window. Cross-domain communication can still be achieved with [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: this might be a silly question, but when both the parent.html and child.html are present at file:///C:/temp/html, shouldnt they share the same origin/domain?

Comment: Figured it... apparently chrome considers files from the local filesystem to be cross-domain. it works as expected on IE. i suppose it will work fine when hosted on a server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `$scope.apply()` does not work. Try `$scope.$apply()`